# Prevent opening of new Window on shift click in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

[image: Shift click by default opens a new window]

I've noticed when I **shift click** on the new tab icon, it opens a **New window**. I want to disable the shift modifier for this or at least force it to open a new Tab instead of a new Window. Bonus points would be disable the shift modifier across the browser UI.

Might be similar to the question: [Prevent the closing of a tab with firefox addon sdk API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588388/prevent-the-closing-of-a-tab-with-firefox-addon-sdk-api/26602970#26602970)

Tried searching https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/ for gBrowser newWindow, open & the such and come up empty. I can't find the XUL where that new Tab icon should be defined. Be good if you could please indicate how you find these UI elements to override!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to noida on #extdev Mozilla IRC, for pointing out: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js#8088

Tbh I don't quite understand how to override **BrowserOpenNewTabOrWindow** so I ended up [overriding at the XUL that calls that function](https://github.com/Webconverger/webconverger-addon/commit/1ee1f5821a2fb9279414979b7b5b4309d80f6865) to **BrowserOpenTab**.

It's not a perfect solution since I ideally want to unbind **OpenBrowserWindow** altogether.